# How is Meteor secure?

Tags: meteor

The docs suggest to use `Meteor.methods` to create methods that are secure.

Is it possible for a user to write code in a browser's console that will allow the user to circumvent security and send arbitrary data to the server database (MongoDB)? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only if the method fails to check its inputs and context. Fortunately, meteor provides the tools to make this task pretty straightforward. Let's look at an example method I used to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330804/safe-methods-in-meteor). `sendMessage` is a method which lets a user send a message in a chat room:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  sendMessage: function(message, roomId) {
    check(message, String);
    check(roomId, String);

    if (!this.user)
      throw new Meteor.Error(401, 'You must be logged in.');

    if (_.isEmpty(message))
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Message must not be empty.');

    var room = Rooms.findOne(roomId);

    if (!room)
      throw new Meteor.Error(404, 'Room not found.');

    if (!_.contains(room.members, this.userId))
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'You are not in the room.');

    return Messages.insert({
      userId: this.userId,
      roomId: roomId,
      message: message
    });
  }
});
```

Here are the validations:

- Ensure the inputs are of the correct type by using [check](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check) (prevents injection attacks).
- Ensure that the user is logged in (see the [accounts api](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_api)).
- Ensure the message is well formed.
- Ensure that the room exists.
- Ensure that the current user is actually in the room.

Contrast this with a naive implementation of `sendMessage`:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  sendMessage: function(message, roomId) {
    return Messages.insert({
      userId: this.userId,
      roomId: roomId,
      message: message
    });
  }
});
```

Here, any connected client could open a terminal and start injecting messages into any chat room. Worse yet, `message` could be an object and cause all sorts of unintended consequences for other clients.

There is no free lunch with security - you should validate everything and assume the worst. However, if you make the effort, you can in fact generate highly secure methods.

I'd strongly recommend having a look at Emily Stark's [Meteor Meets Mallory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79uMp-S23MA) talk where she covers these points in more detail.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I see how the method *itself* is secure, but is it possible for the user to bypass these checks by overriding the Meteor object (or similar), then creating arbitrary methods that don't have those checks? Perhaps the user can request the page manually from inside the very page (inception) and modify the script, then perhaps run it in an iframe with the modified code? Or perhaps run it in the current environment with the carefully overriden methods? Is this possible, or is there something in place on the server-side to ensure that it's not possible?

Comment: Meteor is written with the assumption that the client code could be completely compromised. Regardless of whatever happens on the client, **all database mutations** must pass through the server (assuming the insecure package has been removed). For example, a client could re-implement a method, but it wouldn't matter because meteor only considers client-side methods to be simulations - the real method would have to be run on the server in order for any side effects to occur. And the server method isn't vulnerable unless an attacker gained access to the server itself.